# isosceles and tight triangle

Tags: triangles

[image]

Hi, I was wondering if there is a way to find x with only knowing the length of isosceles triangle and no other piece of information.

Comment: You mean only knowing then length of $OB$? If so, then no, you can't. However, if you know $AB$ or the angle $A,B$ or $O$, as well, then you can.

Comment: I think your gonna need more information. As stated, the angle At O can be anything without changing the setup

Comment: yes OB is 650 that is the length of the triangle

Comment: It probably looks like $\angle ABC$ is $30^\circ$, taking that as an assumption we can calculate x.Otherwise, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. You cannot determine it solely on $\overline{OB}$. Because the length of $\overline{AB}$ isn't defined. You can make a really fat isosceles triangle by making $\overline{AB}$ large or you can make a really skinny isosceles triangle by making $\overline{AB}$ small. This would change $x$.

If you fixed any angle in the isosceles triangle then you can solve it. Or if you fix the length $\overline{AB}$ then you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If $\angle AOD=\angle DOB=y^\circ,\angle OBA=\angle OBD=(90-y)^\circ\implies \angle ABC=y^\circ$

For the right angular triangle $\displaystyle\triangle ABC,\frac x{AB}=\sin y^\circ\implies x=2BD\sin y^\circ$

For the right angular triangle $\displaystyle\triangle ODB,\frac{BD}{650}=\sin y^\circ$

$\implies x=2\sin y^\circ(BD)=2\sin y^\circ(650)\sin y^\circ=1300\cdot\sin^2y^\circ$

Clearly,  the value of $y$ can be arbitrary between $(0,90)$